# How to create a Rally query for a custom field?

Tags: rally

I would like to be able to query a custom field, is this supported?

When I try creating a new rally.sdk.util.Query() with my custom field in the query clause, I don't seem to get any results returned.

Under the User Stories view I'm able to create a custom filter that can filter based on custom fields, so it seems like it should be possible?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to see an example of how you are coding your query but most of the time you add your query to the config object of the thing you are creating so for example in the cardboard component :
        var cardboardConfig = {
             types: ["PortfolioItem", "HierarchicalRequirement"],
             attribute: dropdownAttribute,
             fetch:"Name,FormattedID,Owner,ObjectID,",
             query : "YourAttibute = value"
             cardRenderer: PriorityCardRenderer
        };

Will return a cardboard with only the portfolio items that have an attribute (YourAttribute) whose value equals 'value'. You may also want to use the "toString()" function of the query object to debug and see what string it is actually passing. (Why Rally made that member function "toString" verse "getValue()" like every other member function is beyond me.
Hope that helps,
Dax- Autodesk

Yes, I have been able to query using both custom attributes and standard. I do always build my queries suing the Rally query object. NOTE : There are some oddities that might cause you issues I learned about the hard way. For example The query object always adds "()" to the strings even if empty and if you try and filter with that it returns no results (lame) so you have to code explicitly for the empty query case like:

```
        fullQueryStr = fullQuery.toString();
    // If the query is empty basically All and All empty string silly Rally query otherwise returns nothing
    if (fullQueryStr === "()") {
        fullQuery = "";
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for custom fields though.

E.g. we have a custom field named "Sub-iteration" with possible values 1, 2, 3, or 4.

I've tried editing the Kanban Board to query with AND ("Sub-iteration" = "2") but don't get any results returned.  I've also tried (Sub-iteration = 2), ("Sub-iteration" = 2), and (Sub-iteration = "2") all with the same results.

Have you been able to query cutom fields, or only the default fields provided by Rally?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to make sure you are bringing that field back for the purpose of using it

Somewhere you should have a fetch line, in there you need to list all the fields you plan to access.

Not sure if its the same problem, perhaps put some code out here to look at for more help.